# Basic Maths on AS3 ByteArrays

Tags: actionscript-3, math, arrays

does anyone know if there is any possibility to do simple elementwise math on bytearrays without having to program it explicitely, e.g. a built-in function for multiplying all elements of a bytearray (of type float) by a constant or adding the elements of two bytearrays (with specified datatype)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you consider using `Vector.<Number>` instead of `ByteArray` especially when all elements of array is of the same type?

Then you could use such a code:

```
// create vector with sample data
var floatVector : Vector.<Number> = Vector.<Number>( [5.1, 5.2, 5.3] );

// define a method that will work on each element
function multipleElementByTwo ( item : Number, index : int, vector : Vector.<Number> ) : void {
    vector[index] = item * 2;
}

// see original data
trace( floatVector );

// run through all elements
floatVector.forEach( multipleElementByTwo );

// see modified data
trace( floatVector );
```

Comment: Indeed thats a good and fast solution if you don't already have your data in a bytearray. But things look different if you have the data in a bytearray. In this case you have to convert the bytearray data to a vector at first, then perform your maths and finally have to convert them back to a bytearray and this conversions are pretty time consuming (e.g. for real-time sound handling). A intrinsic function would therefore be a faster way... :)